# Importing csv file into J and using them as variable

Tags: j

I saved this data (20 vectors v)into csv file like this

```
v=:<"1 (? 20 2 $ 20)
makecsv v
v writecsv jpath'~temp/position.csv'
]vcsv =: freads jpath '~temp/position.csv'
fixcsv vcsv
```

, and I could import the csv file by

```
readcsv jpath '~temp/position.csv'
```

However, it doesn't give same result if I name it as

```
w=: readcsv jpath '~temp/position.csv'
diff=: ([{]) ,. ]

0 diff v
0 diff w
```

Actually, 0 diff w gives a length error

Is there any other approach should I use to have same results from both v(original) and w(imported csv data)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write the CSV file, you just have a bunch of ASCII characters. In this case, you've got numbers, spaces, and commas.

When you read the CSV, J has no guarantees about the format or contents. `fixcsv` gets your commas and line-breaks translated into a grid of cells, but J boxes it all to be safe, because it's a bunch of variable-length ASCII strings.

If you want to get back to `v`, you have two things you need to do. The first is to get the dimensions right. CSV files, pretty much by definition, are two-dimensional. If you change your example to write a two-dimensional array to the CSV, you'll find that you have the same shape after `fixcsv readcsv`.

```
u =: 4 5 $ v
   u writecsv jpath'~temp/position.csv'
104
   ] t =: fixcsv freads jpath '~temp/position.csv'
┌────┬─────┬────┬────┬─────┐
│9 11│1 4  │8 3 │3 12│5 4  │
├────┼─────┼────┼────┼─────┤
│7 11│10 11│9 10│0 8 │6 16 │
├────┼─────┼────┼────┼─────┤
│13 8│17 12│13 2│5 19│17 14│
├────┼─────┼────┼────┼─────┤
│2 15│19 10│3 1 │12 7│14 13│
└────┴─────┴────┴────┴─────┘
   $ v
20
   $ u
4 5
   $ t
4 5
```

If you're definitely dealing with a one-dimensional list (albeit of boxed number pairs), then you can [Ravel (`,`)](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/comma) what you read to get it down to one dimension.

```
   $ w
1 20
   $ , w
20
```

Once you have them in the same shape, you need to convert the ASCII text into number arrays. Do that with [Numbers (`".`)](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/quotedot#dyadic).

```
   10 * > {. v
90 110
   10 * > {. , w
|domain error
|   10    *>{.,w
   'a' , > {. , w
a9 11
   10 * _ ". > {. , w
90 110
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a J beginner so you may get a better answer later, but poking at it I think I have found something.

First, the `tables/csv` addon docs state that `readcsv` "Reads csv file into a **boxed** array," emphasis mine, while `writecsv` "Writes an array to a csv file." In other words, `readcsv` and `writecsv` are *not* symmetric operations. And the shapes of the values seem to confirm that:

```
   $ w
1 20
   $ v
20
```

This is also why the `diff` works for `v` but not `w`. If you simply unbox the result, it seems to work better:

```
0 diff 0 { w
┌───┬─────┐
│1 3│1 3  │
├───┼─────┤
 ...
├───┼─────┤
│1 3│5 8  │
└───┴─────┘
```

However, the shapes are *still* not exactly the same:

```
   $ > v
20 2
   $ > 0 { w
20 5
```

I think this is because `readcsv` doesn't know that your values are numeric; you probably need to throw a `".` in there somewhere to decode them.